# How to pass json varaible in controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am new to angularJS. I have some doubts.
I have a json data value in one variable.
How to use that varaible in controller ?
Example

```
$scope.pareseJson($scope.productresult);
```

In `productresult` I have values for brand, size and color.
if I console console.log("prdmake" , prdmake); am getting brand values.

How to pass that variable in controller ?

```
$scope.items = [

                {
                    name: "item1",
                    desc: "Shop By Brand",
                    subitems:

                        {
                            name: "subitem1",
                            desc: "prdmake"
                        }

                }];
```

I want to use prdmake (json variable) in subitems desc:

Answer (score 0):

you can use $scope.items.name to get the value, in 1.4 should work even  $scope.items[name]